# Calling a function within a Instantiated object in Godot 4

Tags: c#, instantiation, godot

Good afternoon, I am working on a chunk loading system for a game I am working on.
I am coming from unity so I am writing all of my code in c#.
I have made a chunk object scene and successfully loaded it and added it to the scene.
The issue I am having is once instantiated I cannot call a function on the chunk object

Below is the code that creates the chunk and attempts to call a function on it

```
        var chunkScene = ResourceLoader.Load<PackedScene>("res://Chunk.tscn");
        // Instantiate the chunk node
        var chunk = chunkScene.Instantiate();
        // Add the chunk to the scene
        AddChild(chunk);
        chunk.DoIt();/*<-- this is an example function that exists on the chunk object that i am trying to call*/
```

I have confirmed that the chunk object is the correct one ( in this case it is a Node3D Named Chunk that has a script attached to it with the function defined but get the following error

`'Node' does not contain a definition for 'DoIt' and no accessible extension method 'DoIt' accepting a first argument of type 'Node' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Which is weird because I would expect the type to be Node3D and not node as using print to get details of the instantiated object gives me the correct type and name.

I am very new to Godot and would welcome any input towards clarifying what I may be doing wrong here.

I have collected information on the spawned object, tried several different methods of instantiation, and confirmed there are no other nodes present.

Comment: I'm not familiar with c#, but AFAIK you have to 1. cast chunk to the correct type `var chunk = chunkScene.Instantiate() as DoItType` or 2. when chunk script is gdscript, you have to do `chunk.Call("DoIt")`.

Comment: casting it as the class name did the trick! you have no idea how long I have been stuck on that.